# Create multiple Instances of Caffe - C++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, computer-vision, gpu, caffe

I want to create multiple instances of Caffe in a single C++ program so I can utilize multiple GPUs, but Caffe appears to be a singleton instance. I can run separate programs that use Caffe and assign each program a unique GPU. The multiple programs method is not as easily manageable as if I was running them all from a single program.

Comment: Running multiple processes being less efficient than a single one is not a given fact.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I was stating that it's more difficult to manage running multiple programs than it is just a single one. I'll clarify that, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

@Apexdev, I was working in similar kind of problem. I wanted to test multiple models on the same dataset. Previously I used to test using different scripts as yours, and now I can invoke all scripts using the same script.
Here is the solution that worked for me...
Header File:

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

Step 1: Define a struct that we will pass to thread arguments

```
Ex. struct thread_Arguments {
    int GPU_id;
    std::string Model;
    std::vector<std::string> list;
};
```

Step 2: Create a function that will perform any action you want

```
 void *MultiscriptInvoke(void *threadarg) {
    struct thread_Arguments *Newthread;
    Newthread = (struct thread_Arguments *) threadarg;
    std::string modelFile = Newthread->Model;
    int GPU_ID = Newthread->GPU_ID;
    // Terminate thread using
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Step 3: Define thread creation

```
pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
pthread_attr_t attr;
void *status;
```

Step 4: Initialize threads

```
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
struct thread_Arguments td[NUM_THREADS];
```

Step 5: Create threads

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    td[i].GPU_ID = GPU1[i];
    td[i].Model = ModelName[i];
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, MultiscriptInvoke, (void *)i );
    if (rc) {
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         exit(-1);
     }
}
```

Step 6: Wait for threads to completions

```
   pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
   for( i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ) {
      rc = pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
      if (rc) {
         cout << "Error:unable to join," << rc << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
```

I hope this will help you. Modify your struct as per your need and create multiple instances.
ref: Thanks to [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm)